# Delete dynamically generated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to generate the dynamic fields but when i am trying to delete the fields rather then deleting the elements in front of the delete button it is deleting from last towards first

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var max_fields = 10;
        var wrapper = $(".more");
        var add_button = $(".add");
        var x = 1;
        $(add_button).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields){
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append('<div id="box'+x+'" class="row"><div class="col-sm-3 mb-3"><select name="feeType[]" class="form-control shadow-sm" required><option value="" selected disabled>Select Fee</option><option value="Admission">Admission Fee</option><option value="Development">Development Fee</option><option value="Annual">Annual Fee</option><option value="Tuition">Tuition Fee</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-3 mb-3"><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control shadow-sm" placeholder="Amount" required></div><div class="col-sm-3 mb-3"><button class="delete btn btn-danger shadow-sm">Delete Fields</button></div></div>'); //add input box
            }else{
                alert('You Reached the limits')
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#box'+x).remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `x`'s value will always be just the number of element that were dynamically created.

A possible solution would be to find the 'remove' button that was clicked and remove it's parent. replace `$('#box'+x).remove();` with this             `$(this).parents('.row').remove();`

A working fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3L986nbj/